# Youtube iframe API with javascript tabs

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube

I'm building an online 'TV' which will use YouTube live-streams for multiple channels.

The channels are contained within tabs. The videos need to be stopped when changing tabs otherwise you can hear the audio in the background.

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/matlow/08k4csuh/

I've managed to turn the 'Channel 1' off when changing to another channel with:

```
  var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("tvscreen")[0].contentWindow;
```

and

```
 iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
```

In the tab javascript for loop which also handles the `tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";`

I think I need to use the for loop to call each instance of the iframe... but I'm quite new to javascript so I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

It will also help to use `iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');` so the video plays automatically again when clicking on the relevant tab... but again I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

I've been working on this for a few days so if anyone had any tips or pointers I would really appreciate it!

Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using YouTube's API properly. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

In your fiddle, programmatic `play` is not possible, because you can't know when the YouTube player is ready, as you are not the one initialising it. Your attempts to `play` the video might take place too early.

Programmatic `pause` (you managed to pause the first video) is possible thanks to `enablejsapi=1` in the iframe src and the fact that the player is ready at that point.

Here's a fork of your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/raven0us/ancr2fgz

I added a couple of comments. Check those out.

```js
// load YouTube iframe API as soon as possible, taken from their docs
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// initialised players are kept here so we don't have to destroy and reinit
var ytPlayers = {};

function mountChannel(channel) {
    var player;
    var iframeContainer = document.querySelectorAll('#' + channel + ' iframe');

    // if the channel & iframe we want to "mount" exist, check for playing iframes before doing anything else
    if (iframeContainer.length > 0) {
        // Object.keys() is ECMA 5+, sorry about this, but no easy to check if an object is empty
        // alternatively, you could have an array, but in that case, you won't be able to fetch a specific player as fast
        // if you don't need that functionality, array is as good cause you will just loop through active players and destroy them
        var activePlayersKeys = Object.keys(ytPlayers);
        if (activePlayersKeys.length > 0) { // if players exist in the pool, destroy them
            for (var i = 0; i < activePlayersKeys.length; i++) {
                var activeChannel = activePlayersKeys[i];
                var activePlayer = ytPlayers[activeChannel];

                activePlayer.getIframe().classList.remove('playing'); // mark pause accordingly, by removing class, not necessary
                activePlayer.pauseVideo();
            }
        }

        // check if player already initialised and if player exists, check if it has resumeVideo as a function
        if (ytPlayers.hasOwnProperty(channel)) {
            ytPlayers[channel].playVideo();
        } else {
            var iframe = iframeContainer[0];
            player = new YT.Player(iframe, {
                events: {
                    'onReady': function (event) {
                        // event.target is the YT player
                        // get the actual DOM node iframe nad mark it as playing via a class, styling purposes, not necessary
                        event.target.getIframe().classList.add('playing');
                        // play the video
                        event.target.playVideo();
                        // video may not autoplay all the time in Chrome, despite its state being cued and this event getting triggered, this happens due to a lot of factors 

                    },
                    // you should also implement `onStateChange` in order to track video state (as a result of user actions directly via YouTube controls) - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
                }
            });

            // append to the list
            ytPlayers[channel] = player;
        }
    }
}

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    // YouTube API will call this when it's ready, only then attempt to "mount" the initial channel
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}
```

This is the first time I worked with YouTube's iframe API, but it seems reasonable.